# No module named 'tabulate' (0.8.9)

Tags: python, pip

I have tried to install tabulate with `pip` and `pip3` in my virtual environment and the installation goes well.

```
Requirement already up-to-date: tabulate in ./word2box_pytorch/word2box_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.8.9)
```

When I try to execute the code it tells me that it does not find the module (no module named 'tabulate').

```
from tabulate import tabulate
```

I've seen that this is a widespread problem, are there any solutions?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Is the code running in the virtual environment? Did you verify that the virtual environment (rather than, for example, the system Python installation) contains the installed code? We can't tell you how it went wrong without seeing exactly what you did.

Comment: After checking that you use the virtual env, check that installation path is on the PYTHONPATH environment var and that running `python` tells you you're on 3.8. Sometimes `conda` or similar package-management tools override package access in odd ways.

Comment: i see the package in pip freeze and also checked that code is running in venv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to close the editor and reopen it, verify with `pip freeze` that the package was installed, then control that the code was executed in the venv. Now it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `where python` command in cmd to find the path that python is installed in. then you can use this command -

```
[python path] -m pip install tabulate
```

you can also unstall to the current user with the command:
`pip install tabulate --user`

you can also try on windows:

```
set TABULATE_INSTALL=lib-only
pip install tabulate
```

for more info you can look at https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/